# Create a new category in Shopware 6 get error /0/translations/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b/name

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When trying to create a new category, I get this error.

```
/0/translations/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b/name This value should not be blank.
```

This is my array:(As you can see. My error is related to the key's name. But the key's name has a value)

```
[
  0 => [
  "categories" => [
    "id" => "7767b163a5124c83ad8f6c701ffabade",
    "parentId" => null,
    "name" => "Supply",
    "path" => "professional",
    "level" => 5,
    "active" => true,
    "description" => null,
    "translations" => [
       "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b" =>[
         "defaultLanguageId"=>"2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
         "name" => "Professional",
         "metaTitle" => "",
         "metaDescription" => "",
         "description" => "",
       ],
       "f7e5c2a4bb194c339714f9798d8f853d" => [
         "name" => "Materiale Profession",
         "defaultLanguageId"=>"2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
         "metaTitle" => "",
         "metaDescription" => "",
         "description" => "",
        ],
        "51d36b57c6144235bcb0332a3ca20a5c" => [
          "name" => "Profesional",
         "defaultLanguageId"=>"2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
          "metaTitle" => "",
          "metaDescription" => "",
          "description" => "",
        ],
        "66623e62998e42c695fba0d22b023c63" =>[
          "name" => "Professionnel",
         "defaultLanguageId"=>"2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
          "metaTitle" => "",
          "metaDescription" => "",
          "description" => "",
        ],
      ]
    ]
 ]]
```

Also, it doesn't work without translation.
I don't have a problem with creating products.

```
 $this->productRepository->create($products, $context);
```

I get this error only when I'm going to create the category

```
 $this->categoryRepository->create($category, $context);
```

Does anyone know where my problem is?

Comment: Do you want to write multiple translations? Meaning for multiple languages at once or do you just care about one language?

Comment: Yes, I need to be in multiple translations. I updated my question.

Comment: Is this the original value from the code? Can you `var_export($array)` the array?

Comment: Also can you try leaving out the `defaultLanguageId` in each of the sub-array - I don't understand why they would be needed

Comment: Thank you for your attention, Alex. I didn't get the right error. It was just a futile attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for the error is the extra `categories` array key in your example. The repository expects a list of associative arrays with the fields of the entities as keys, that means in your example you only provide the `categories` field, which is no valid category payload.

Additionally in your case you could greatly simplify your code as it seems that you only want to update the name in different languages.

You can try the following payload:

```php
[
  0 => [
    "id" => "7767b163a5124c83ad8f6c701ffabade",
    "parentId" => null,
    "name" => [
      "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b" => "Professional",
      "f7e5c2a4bb194c339714f9798d8f853d" => "Materiale Profession",
        ...
    ],
    "path" => "professional",
    "level" => 5,
    "active" => true,
    "description" => null,
  ]
]
```

Notice the missing array index `categories`.

Comment: Yes, I did not use the correct format for the array. Thank you. And I got an irrelevant error That's why I didn't understand where the problem really was